# Mongoose: Running Scheduled Job Query by Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a scheduled job for patients in a hospital. The patients will be informed every month by their `reg_date`.

I'm using `new Date().getDate()` inside my scheduled Jobs to run at 8.00 AM in the morning to send SMS to my patients. Meanwhile, I had been using string format date to save `reg_date` in my mongoDB. Here is snippets of my mongoDB docs :

```
{
    customer: "John",
    reg_date: "2017-02-17T16:39:26.969Z"
}
```

I've ben surfing for solutions but it turns out nothing, so I decided to post myself. Here is what i am trying to do :

```
customer.find({"reg_date.getDate()" : new Date(2017, 03, 17).getDate()})
    .then(function(data) {
      for (var key in data.length) {
          sendTheSMS(key[data]);
      };
    });
```

E.g: What I am doing is "I want to get every patient who register at 17th day of the month and send them a SMS".

Any help will be appreciated. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of bit complex query you need to use aggregation method instead regular find method.

`$project` this will help you to project your fields, here we are creating a new temporary field `day` with only date of the `reg_date`. Then we query using the new field day and we get the result.

This temp field `day` will never added to your schema or model, it is just like temp view we are creating like in SQL.

Here i projected only customer and day but Please project all the fields necessary in the result.

```
function getCustomerList(day, callback){
    customer.aggregate([
      {
         $project:{
            "customer": "$customer",   //repeat the same for all field you want in result
            "reg_date": "$reg_date",
            "day":{$dayOfMonth:"$reg_date"}  //put day of month in 'day' 
         }
       },
      {
        $match:{
          "day": day  //now match the day with the incoming day value
      }
     },
   ], function(err, result){
        callback(err, result);            
   })
}

getCustomerList(17, function(err, result){   // call the function like this with date you want
   // Process the err & result here
});
```

Result will be like this

```
[{
 "_id" : ObjectId("571f2da8ca97eb10163e6e17"),
 "customer" : "John",
 "reg_date" : ISODate("2016-04-17T08:58:16.414Z"),
 "day" : 17
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("571f2da8ca97eb10163e6e17"),
 "customer" : "Prasanth",
 "reg_date" : ISODate("2016-04-17T08:58:16.414Z"),
 "day" : 17
}]
```

Ignore the `day` field projected during your process...

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But still, I want John to appear again if i entered date 17 despite of any months or year. Can I won't get one with that query. :)

Comment: what version of mongodb is installed?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11

Comment: the answer helped you?

Comment: thankyou for detailed explanation, it's working now. I took time looking through what is `aggregation` and `$project` thing first, so i could use them next time. Cheers bud!

Answer (score 1):

With `reg_date` in string you can't query for day of month as it only works with [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/#date). I suggest first you convert the string in `reg_date` in all your documents with a script.

Then the following query should work

```
customer.aggregate([
{
    $project:{
            "document": "$$ROOT",   //to get the whole document
            "day":{$dayOfMonth:"$date"}  //put day of month in 'day' 
           }
    },
{
    $match:{
        "day": 17  //match 17
        }
    },

], function(data) {
  for (var key in data.length) {
      sendTheSMS(key[data]);
  };
})
```

Comment: Hi Talha, your answer looks promising to me. I am still new in mongoDB and mongoose ODM. Can you please elaborate the `$project` section? Cheers.

Comment: It's used in the aggregation pipeline. The official definition is helpful: " [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) Passes along the documents with the requested fields to the next stage in the pipeline."

Answer (score 0):

Use greater than and less than

```
var previousDate =new Date(2017, 1, 16);   //month starts with 0
var nextDate=new Date(2017, 1, 18);

customer.find({reg_date : { $gt:previousDate,$lt:nextDate}})
.then(function(data) {
  for (var key in data.length) {
    sendTheSMS(key[data]);
  };
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But still, I want John to appear again if i entered date 17 despite of any months or year. Can I won't get one with that query. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `reg_date` is stored as a string, and not a Date/ISODate, you're limited as to what kind of query you can run (so I concur with the comment in one of the other answers that you should consider converting them to proper ISODate).

Considering that you want to query a date string for entries with a particular day-of-month, you can use a [regular expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query:

```
customer.find({ reg_date : /-17T/ })
```

Or, dynamically:

```
let today = new Date();
let dom   = ('00' + today.getDate()).slice(-2); // zero-pad day of month
let re    = new RegExp('-' + dom + 'T');

customer.find({ reg_date : re })
```

You should also read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) regarding speed optimizations, but still, regex queries aren't very fast.